# Gradient alpha display problem in GLSL shading

Tags: texturing, materials, blender-internal-render-engine, 3d-view, transparency

I found a problem when I import the cloud texture with a gradient alpha into blender.

I have tried both bi and cycle render engine and the transparent parts looks weird when I change viewport to the material mode. it shows fine only when the object is activated.

Changing viewport to render mode is not my option. I want to animate the cloud and it would be perfect if I can see the gradient transparent Correctly.

The goal I would like to achieved is something like the picture below.

[image]

Is this problem can be fix?

Here is the file: [file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BxmcG431eZsUQ1RpWkYwSHp0bFE)

Comment: Can you please either post the blend or show us the material settings? How are you using BI and Cycles at the same time? Afaik materials for either are incompatible with each other.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and sorry for my bad english. I tried BI and cycle in different file and have the same issue. There is a file attached in the end of the post.

Comment: Then what is the end goal of this if not rendering? This is most likely bad related to lack of possibilities of showing alpha of material shading mode

Comment: If the viewport shows the correct alpha then I can do composition work (a little bit like the projection mapping) without changing to the render mode, and it is much faster to animate the cloud also.